# Bizarre ignoring of font size when canvas created dynamically - reposted

Tags: canvas, font-size

Ive been requested to repost this question. First it was flagged as *duplicate with CSS issue*, but I dont use CSS. This is a JS anomaly

These two codes should do the same thing.
But, the first with dynamic canvas ignores the font size, and **scales the font bigger in larger window!**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var n=0, c=[], ct=[]
for (n=0; n<2; n++){
  c[n] = document.createElement('canvas');
  c[n].id = "C"+n;
  c[n].style.width = (400*n+70)+"px";
  c[n].style.height = (400*n+70)+"px";
  c[n].style.border = "2px solid";
 
  document.body.appendChild(c[n]);
  ct[n] = c[n].getContext("2d");
  ct[n].font="30px Arial"
  ct[n].fillText("Hello",3,30)
}
</script></body></html>
```

Here two canvas are created inline, and this time it works as expected

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="C0" width="70" height="70" style="border: 2px solid;"> </canvas>
<canvas id="C1" width="470" height="470" style="border: 2px solid;"> </canvas>

<script>
 var c =[], ct=[]
 c[0]=document.getElementById("C0")
 ct[0] = c[0].getContext("2d")
 c[1] = document.getElementById("C1")
 ct[1] = c[1].getContext("2d")
 ct[0].font="30px Arial"
 ct[1].font="30px Arial"
 ct[0].fillText("Hello",3,30)
 ct[1].fillText("Hello",3,30)

</script> </body></html>
```

JS does have some strange flaws, and I would appreciate it if this question can be kept open for opinions, rather than swept under the carpert as 'a CSS issue' !

Answer (score 0):

It seems related to the confusion in

style.width vs width values

both codes below set the canvas size, but one will affect how text is displayed!

```
 c[n].style.width = (400*n+70)+"px";
 c[n].style.height = (400*n+70)+"px";
```

or

```
c[n].width = 400*n+70
c[n].height = 400*n+70
```